# Kotlin : list of primes till n

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make a function in kotlin to return list of primes till input argument n.
I have tried below code but it is returning list with multiple same digits.

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

fun main() {
    
    fun primes(n : Int):MutableList<Int>{
        var li : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(2)
        for(num in 2..n+1){
            for(i in 2..num){
                if(num % i == 0)
                break
                else
                li.add(num)
            }
        }
        return li
    }
    
    print(primes(7))
}
```

Output :

```
[2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

What's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
    fun primes(n : Int):MutableList<Int>{
        var li : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(2)
        for(num in 2..n+1){
            for(i in 2..num){
                if(num % i == 0){
                    if(num==i) li.add(num) else break
                } 
            }
        }
        return li
    }
```

basically you break when `num` is divisible by `i` and they're not the same number
this will fix adding the number for every non divisible number smaller than `num`

Answer (score 8):

This is a prime example (!) of where a loop can be replaced by more functional-style code — in this case, the [`none()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/none.html) function:

```
fun primes(n: Int): MutableList<Int> {
    val li = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (num in 2..n) {
        if ((2 until num).none{ num % it == 0 })
            li.add(num)
    }
    return li
}
```

To explain: the `none()` function returns true only if the lambda returns false for every item of the list.  And `it` means the parameter value (imagine `it ->` in the lambda).  So it's checking that num can be divided by none of the numbers from 2 to num-1 (which is of course the definition of a prime).  This is not only shorter, but also hopefully easier to read.  (Once you're used to the functional style, of course.)

In fact, you can replace the outer loop too, and make the whole thing a one-liner:

```
fun primes(n: Int)
    = (2..n).filter{ num -> (2 until num).none{ num % it == 0 } }
```

That version is purely functional, but perhaps a little too compressed to be easily readable.  It takes the numbers from 2 to n, and keeps only those which are prime (as described above).  (`filter()` returns a list, so there's no need to create one manually.)

However, in algorithmic terms, there's no need to check *every* possible divisor up to the number you're testing — you only need to check for the prime divisors.  That's a more efficient approach.  Because it uses the list of primes you've already found, you can't do it with a simple `filter()` as in the second example.  But you can easily tweak the first example to do that: just replace the `if ((2 until num).none{` with `if (li.none{`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit advanced for me but I am going to look it up definitely.

Comment: Oh, forgot one more thing: although you need to create a MutableList, it's usually better to declare the function as returning a List (i.e. implicitly upcasting it to the non-mutable super-interface). The caller is very unlikely to want to modify it, and that gives you more options for tweaking the implementation later if needed. Also, List is covariant so that gives the caller more options for refining types, as well as avoiding some types of bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(i in 2..num){
            if(num % i == 0)
            break
            else
            li.add(num)
        }
```

This adds `num` to the list `li` once for *every* `i` less than `num` that doesn't divide `num`. For example, for `num == 5`, we check 2, 3 and 4, and for each of these we add 5 to the list, so it appears three times.

Instead of `break`ing out of the inner loop, try `continue`ing the outer loop (which also aborts the inner loop). If the inner loop runs to completion, only then should you add `num` to the list of primes:

```
    outer@for(num in 2..n+1){
        for(i in 2..num){
            if(num % i == 0) {
                continue@outer; // Not a prime. Continue with the next candidate.
            }
        }
        li.add(num) // No divisors found. It must be prime!
    }
```

Comment: [2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7] this is output I am getting with this modification with input 7.